# Power BI / Power Query - CSV tags to Dimensions on facts without a unique ID?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a fact table

| Date | Name | tags | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-23 | Purchase 12333 | everyday,chemist,health | 123.83 |
| 2020-01-22 | Purchase 12333 | everyday,food | 232.99 |
| 2020-01-23 | Purchase 48321 | everyday,supermarket,health | 23.11 |

I want to create a star schema for the tags column so I can see all records for "everyday" (show 3 records) and then select food (show 1 record) or both health and everyday (show 2 records).

I can create a new table in power query by separating by comma and assigning a surrogate key but I also need to be able to target the fact table when there is no obvious unique key (Name is not guaranteed to be unique). What can I do to create a surrogate key to target the fact table? Is there a hashing technique based on say 3 different columns (date, name and amount) in the fact table to generate a unique key?

Comment: How many tags are there in you data. You can make a long table with the name and the separated tags then use the purchase name as a key to join

Comment: Not many tags, but the "name" column is not guaranteed to be unique, thus the hash off three different columns which are guaranteed to be unique (pretty much!)

Comment: So your options, from my thought process, are make a binary column for each tag in the table to filter the tags or create a key by combining the columns as a text field and separated by a delimiter. If you are just looking for everyday you can make a binary column for every day and use that as a filter. Look up Text.Contains in power query.

Comment: "can create a new table in power query by separating by comma and assigning a surrogate key but I also need to be able to target the fact table."
Does this tags appear in some order/or are connected by group? example "health" is always third. You may create a dimTag dimTag2 etc; Two columns: TagValue, KeyTag. everyday 1; In main table also split tags to column, and add KeyTag joining by TagValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a snowflake, and it may miss the mark based on your comments aboout you having chosen not to assign a surrogate key, but it *might* still be what your looking for, or at least help you get there.

I start with your table as a table named Fact:
[image]

Then I add an index column and rename it to ID:
[image]

Then I reference the Fact table to create a new one I call NamesAndTags, and I then select the ID and tags columns and remove other columns, and then use `= Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"tags", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "tags")` to get this:
[image]

Then I reference the IDsAndTags table to create a new one I call Tags, and I then use `= Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"tags"}))` to get this:

[image]

Then I Close & Apply and go to the Model view and change the relationships from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

by changing Cross filter direction to Both.

Then in Power BI, I can create a table and a filter where I can do this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's my M code for the IDsAndTags:

```
let
    Source = Fact,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"ID", "tags"}),
    Custom1 = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {{"tags", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "tags"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1,{{"tags", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Here's my M code for the Tags:

```
let
    Source = IDsAndTags,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"tags"}))
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```